# How to solve proportions involving vector cross products?

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

I have the following proportion $\vec{JV} \times \vec{F_v} = \vec{JM} \times \vec{F_m}$ and all members are known except the magnitude of the vector $\vec F_m$, like described by [another question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/264148/expressing-virtual-force-in-terms-of-muscle-contraction-force) in greater details.

Can someone please suggest how to express $|\vec{F_m}|$ in terms of $\vec{JV}, \vec{JM}$, $\vec{F_v}$ and $\hat{F_m}$, where $\hat{F_m}$ is a direction of the $\vec{F_m}$?

Here is a graphical representation of what I'm talking about:
[image: 2]]

Comment: Is $\vec JV$ intended to be a vector from point $J$ to point $V$? In that case, $\vec{JV}$ would seem more appropriate.

Comment: you are right, I've updated the question

Comment: The direction of $\vec F_m$ is known, but not its magnitude.

Comment: @sammygerbil you are absolutely correct, I've updated the question and added illustration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking simply how to find $x$ such that
$$x(\vec a\times\vec u) = \vec c$$
where $\vec a$, $\vec u$, $\vec c$ are given vectors (and $\vec u$ has unit length, although this is not relevant).
Such $x$ exists if and only if $\vec a\times \vec u$ is a multiple of $\vec c$ and can be calculated simply as
$$x = \frac{|\vec c|}{|\vec a\times\vec u|}.$$

In your case $\vec c=\vec{JV} \times \vec{F_v}$, $\vec a = \vec{JM}$, $\vec u = \hat{F_m}$ and you want to find $x=|\vec F_m|$.